# building opentripplaner gtfs.zip

Tags: java, routing, tomcat, transit

I am building a journey planner app using opentripplanner. i have followed their two minutes tutorial in which we just run webapp which uses pre build graph.obj file, it works fine.
But in next five minutes tutorial they shows how can i build .obj from a zip gtfs, while i try to do so i got these errors, i try had to figure them out !

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It was http proxy problem.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @sgrieve He is the author. This solves the problem so it is an answer. More details are needed though. It's not so useful for other people in its current form.